# mongodb insert error not giving any response in save fuction

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

i trying to save some data to mongodb.  in my controller , when i try to save the data it is not
giving me any 
response in the controller log function. after the save method console log it giving response.

by the way i have database ready and running ok.

server.js

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/notification', function (err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("database running")
})

app.post('/users/push-token', controller.saveToken)
```

controller.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var Token = require('../model/token');

exports.saveToken = (req, res) => {


    var tokenData = req.body.token.value;
    var userData = req.body.user.username;

    console.log("save token------------->", tokenData)
    console.log("save token------------->", userData)

    console.log(Token)

    /// to this point everything ok . console ok. but 


    var query = new Token({
        token: tokenData,
        user: userData,
    }).save((err, result) => {
        if (err)
            res.send('Error');
        else
            console.log("token saved");
            res.send(result);
    })

    /// this also print in console

    console.log("save token-------------oooooooooooooooo>")

}
```

model.js

```
var mongoose =  require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var SchemaOption = {
    timestamps: true,
    toJSON: {
        virtuals: true
    }
}

var tokenSchema = new Schema({
    token : String,
    user: String,
} , SchemaOption);

var Token = mongoose.model("token", tokenSchema);

module.exports = Token;
```

Comment: Have you checked your terminal, do you see any error there ?

Comment: no error in terminal...........

Comment: Can you change `var Token = require('../model/token');
` to `var Token = mongoose.model('token');` and try with this update. 
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you're connecting to the db with MongoClient from the native driver. Mongoose will not have any idea about this connection outside of itself.

By default, mongoose Models will buffer actions to be sent to the db until a connection is made ( within mongoose ). [check the faq here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html)

instead of `MongoClient.connect(..)` use `mongoose.connect(..)`

[Mongoose connection docs are here.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)